# psql: changed client encoding to UTF8 but still get error message about LATIN1 encoding

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, psql, iso-8859-1

In a bash script the following command:

```
psql -h ${DATABASE_IP} -U ${USERNAME} -d ${DB_NAME} -n -q -f "${SKRIPTDIR}/some_script.psql" -o "${LOGDIR}/${LOGFILE}.log" -v "SCHEMA=${SCHEMA_NAME}"
```

...resulted in the following error message:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
```

Using the following command:

```
psql -h "<IP ADDRESS>" -U "<USERNAME>" -d "<DATABASE>" -c "SHOW client_encoding"
```

... I saw that the client encoding was LATIN1 (for the databae server it is UTF8).

In order to have the same encoding for both client and server I created a file called .psqlrc in directory /etc.

This file contains the following line of code:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';
```

... see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/multibyte.html

To check whether the client encoding was adjusted, I ran the following command again:

```
psql -h "<IP ADDRESS>" -U "<USERNAME>" -d "<DATABASE>" -c "SHOW client_encoding"
```

As expected, the result was now:

```
client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
```

SO BOTH CLIENT AND SERVER APPARENTLY NOW HAVE THE SAME CHARACTER ENCODING.

But when I ran the bash-script again I got exactly the same error as before, namely:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
```

What is going on here? I don't get it.

---

P.S.: Additionally I checked that the server_encoding is indeed UTF8 by running the following command:

```
psql -h "<IP ADDRESS>" -U "<USERNAME>" -d "<DATABASE>" -c "SHOW server_encoding"
```

... Result:

```
server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
```

---

P.P.S.: There is no statement in the bash file, which changes the character encoding.

---

P.P.P.S.: The content of script "some_script.psql" looks as follows:

```
set search_path to :SCHEMA

select foo
  from stored_procedure_xyz ();

copy (select column_1,
             ...
             column_n
        from t_table_xyz
     ) to stdout with delimiter '  ' csv header;
```

... NB: nowhere in procedure stored_procedure_xyz() the character encoding of the database client is changed.

---

---

P.P.P.P.S: The whole thing works except for one schema:

```
 psql -h ${DATABASE_IP} -U ${USERNAME} -d ${DB_NAME} -n -q -f "${SKRIPTDIR}/some_script.psql" -o "${LOGDIR}/${LOGFILE}.log" -v "SCHEMA=${SCHEMA_NAME}"
```

As long as variable SCHEMA_NAME is not set to this one specific schema, the error message does not occur.

In that schema there seems to be some data, which causes the problem. I just don't get why. Both the database server encoding and the database client encoding is UTF8. So why would it matter, if some byte sequence does not exist in LATIN1?

Comment: What is the *database encoding*? It's a good start if the server and the client can agree on an encoding, but if the database encoding can't store a given character, then that's no use. The error message indicates that it tries to convert to Latin1 (a.k.a ISO-8859-1) which can't represent U+201E.

Comment: the server_encoding is UTF8, which I checked by running the following command: psql -h "<IP ADDRESS>" -U "<USERNAME>" -d "<DATABASE>" -c "\l"

Comment: Please show the result of `SHOW server_encoding;`. Also, show the SQL statement that causes the error. Is there a statement in the script that changes `client_encoding`?

Comment: the result of "SHOW server_encoding;" is UTF8

Comment: Does "stored_procedure_xyz" alter the encoding?

Comment: no, it does not change it

Comment: What happens if you execute the COPY by hand?

Comment: just found out: the whole thing works except for one schema ! ... see my updated post

Comment: Probably some table or column in that particular schema doesn't use UTF-8 encoding, but LATIN1 + you have used `„` in `some_script.psql`. This character is a problem for LATIN1 encoding.